# Departmental restriction against unsafePerformIO

Tags: haskell, coding-style, monads, unsafe-perform-io

There has been some talk at work about making it a department-wide policy of prohibiting the use of `unsafePerformIO` and its ilk.  Personally, I don't really mind as I've always maintained that if I found myself wanting to use it, it usually meant that I need to rethink my approach.

Does this restriction sound reasonable?  I seem to remember reading somewhere that it was included mainly for FFI, but I can't remember where I read that at the moment.

edit:
Ok, that's my fault.  It wouldn't be restricted where it's reasonably needed, ie. FFI.  The point of the policy is more to discourage laziness and code smells.

Comment: Wow, the idea of an official policy to explicitly prohibit using `unsafePerformIO` strikes me as worrying on many levels. I'm not sure which is worse--completely prohibiting a tool useful for FFI, debugging, etc., or that something has presumably *motivated* this policy...

Comment: Your department should have code reviews instead.  If someone new to Haskell use unsafePerformIO to cut corners, the reviewer will notice it, and you can fix it together.  Rules are stupid.  Communication is smart.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A lot of core libraries like `ByteString` use `unsafePerformIO` under the hood, for example to customize memory allocation.

When you use such a library, you're trusting that the library author has proven the referential transparency of their exported API, and that any necessary preconditions for the user are documented.  Rather than a blanket ban, your department should establish a policy and a review process for making similar assurances internally.

Comment: As one of the authors of `ByteString` I'm not at all convinced that `unsafePerformIO` is a good idea in that library. We have had several cases where the `unsafePerformIO` caused real (subtle) bugs.

I think it could be implemented as efficiently without using `unsafePerformIO`. Instead it should use GHC's `MutableByteArray#` type in the `ST` monad.

Comment: @dcoutts: Very interesting.  Would that expose `ST` to the user and require them to call `runST`, or would you be able to hide that somehow?

Comment: The external API would be exactly the same, i.e. pure. Internally there would be no IO and no `unsafePerformIO`. Basically where the current code calls `unsafePerformIO`, the new code would call `runST`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  You'd replace the `ForeignPtr Word8` in `ByteString` with `MutableByteArray# s`?  In that case, I'm not sure how you'd deal with the state token `s`.  Does it become part of the user-visible `ByteString` type or do you quantify it away somehow?

Answer (score 12):

Well, there *are* valid uses for `unsafePerformIO`. It's not there just to be decorative, or as a temptation to test your virtue. None of those uses, however, involve adding meaningful side effects to everyday code. Here's a few examples of uses that can *potentially* be justified, with various degrees of suspicion:

- Wrapping a function that's impure internally, but has no externally observable side effects. This is the same basic idea as the `ST` monad, except that here the burden is on the programmer to show that the impurity doesn't "leak".
- Disguising a function that's deliberately impure in some restricted way. For instance, write-only impurity looks the same as total purity "from the inside", since there's no way to observe the output that's produced. This can be useful for some kinds of logging or debugging, where you explicitly *don't* want the consistency and well-defined ordering required by the `IO` monad. An example of this is `Debug.Trace.trace`, which I sometimes refer to as `unsafePerformPrintfDebugging`.
- Introspection on pure computations, producing a pure result. A classic example is something like the [unambiguous choice operator](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unamb), which can run two equivalent pure functions in parallel in order to get an answer quicker.
- Internally unobservable breaking of referential transparency, such as introducing nondeterminism when initializing data. As long as each impure function is evaluated only once, referential transparency will be effectively preserved during any single run of the program, even if the same faux-pure function called with the same arguments gives different results on different runs.

The important thing to note about all of the above is that the resulting impurity is carefully controlled and limited in scope. Given a more fine-grained system of controlling side-effects than the all-purpose `IO` monad, these would all be obvious candidates for slicing off bits of semi-purity, much like the controlled mutable state in the aforementioned `ST` monad.

---

*Post scriptum:* If a hard-line stance against any non-required use of `unsafePerformIO` is being considered, I *strongly* encourage 
extending the prohibition to include `unsafeInterleaveIO` and any functions that allow observation of its behavior. It's at least as sketchy as some of the `unsafePerformIO` examples I listed above, if you ask me.

Comment: You just need to realise when you use it for things like trace, or unanb that you are no longer programming in Haskell. You are writing a new "primitive" that cannot be written in Haskell and exporting it to the nice clean Haskell world.

Answer (score 7):

unsafePerformIO is the runST of the IO monad. It is sometimes essential. However, unlike runST, the compiler cannot check that you  are preserving referential transparency.

So if you use it, the programmer has a burden to explain why the use is safe. It shouldn't be banned, it should be accompanied with evidence.

Answer (score 4):

Outlawing `unsafePerformIO` in "application" code is an excellent idea. In my opinion there is no excuse for `unsafePerformIO` in normal code and in my experience it is not needed. It is really not part of the language so you are not really programming in Haskell any more if you use it. How do you know what it even means?

On the other hand, using `unsafePerformIO` in an FFI binding is reasonable if you know what you are doing.

Comment: You may not use unsafe functions directly, but if you use Data.Dynamic, the ST monad, etc then you know that they have legitimate uses and not just in FFI code.

Answer (score 3):

Outlawing unsafePerformIO is a terrible idea, because it effectively locks code into the IO monad: for example, a c library binding will almost always be in the IO monad - however, using unsafePerformIO a higher-level purely functional library can be built on top of it.

Arguably, unsafePerformIO reflects the compromise between the highly stateful model of the personal computer and the pure, stateless model of haskell; even a function call is a stateful from the computer's point of view since it requires pushing arguments onto a stack, messing with registers, etc., but the usage is based on the knowledge that these operations do in fact compose functionally.